# Error: Video File field required

Tags: safecracker, file-uploads

Good day,
I am getting an error trying to implement a channel form. Here is my code:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="upload_video" return="http://poliwatch.info/mypoliwatch"}
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="{title}" onkeyup="liveUrlTitle();"><br>

    <label for="url_title">URL Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="url_title" id="url_title" value="{url_title}"><br>

    <label for="video_file">Video File</label>
    <input type="file" name="video_file"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="{site_url}/images/uploads/videos" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="video_file_hidden_file" value="{video_file}{file_name}{/video_file}"/><br>

    <label for="description">Video Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" id="description" value="{description}"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

{/exp:channel:form}
```

I think the problem is `name="{site_url}/images/uploads/videos"`

Comment: You are going to need to provide a bit more information such as EE version and what fieldtypes you are using in your channel form. Along with what errors you are receiving, when are the errors produced (on page load, on submit, on editing or something else) and any other information the might help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I changed the input tags for the video_file field to {field:video_file} and I got it to work!